# My simple HTTP request results in 400 status code in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request

I'm trying to access a particular profile by name on SoundCloud but I'm always getting the `400` status code. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code.

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://soundcloud.com/lifeofdesiigner', function (err, response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode, response.headers);
});
```

And this is my output.

```
400 {
      'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
      'content-type': 'text/html',
       date: 'Sat, 02 Apr 2016 11:25:08 GMT',
       server: 'am/2',
      'set-cookie': [ 'sc_anonymous_id=473227-393077-384395-502205; path=/; expires=Tue, 31 Mar 2026 11:25:08 GMT; domain=.soundcloud.com' ],
       via: 'sssr',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'content-length': '15054',
       connection: 'close'
}
```

**Edit:** I tried the same with `curl` and got the proper response with `200` status code and the requested resource. It just wouldn't work with NodeJS' `http` or `request` modules.

Comment: can you `console.log(err)` ?

Comment: `console.log(err)` shows `null`.

Comment: Ok try the code that we posted Now. And the tell what console.log(body) output

Comment: the `console.log(body)` says I must have JavaScript enabled on my browser or that I should update my browser.

Comment: Where you check the console log on the backend or front end.

Comment: hmmm !!! Ok let me c again

Comment: Then, that means the data on the page `https://soundcloud.com/lifeofdesiigner` is produced by javascript. You may try studying [soudcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript) to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(err)` will be null,

If you do like this,

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://soundcloud.com/lifeofdesiigner', function (err, response, body) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(response.statusCode, response.headers);
    console.log(body);
});
```

First will log will be null, second log, soundcloud server is responding with 400 because it fails to find cookie, third log will be html file.